# hash function ( multiplication method) efficiency,

Tags: hash

how is possible to measure or predict efficiency of Hash function (multiplication method) ?

for example when apply a set of input with large range difference between input numbers, amount of collision parameter is high. but when I apply number with little difference between input numbers , collision is low.

is there any way to predict efficiency of hash function? and why the number of collision is high when the input range  difference is high?

I've written code for multiplication method like this:

Table_size: Memory size,

Input: input number,

Output: output (address of table ),

ce:=((sqrt(5))-1);

ce := ce / 2.00;

output:=Floor(table_size*frac(input * ce));

Comment: This is an awful broad question. Can you limit it to a specific language and perhaps add a code example so that people can answer more specifically?

Comment: @Palu Macil  ,I added my hash function code, (generating memory address )